# Probability question of hats

Tags: probability

Five bald men wearing hats go to a party, and when they arrived they put their hats in a dark closet. During the party, someone yells, “Fire!” and the men rush to the closet, grab a hat at random, and leave. What is the probability that

(a) exactly four get the right hats?

(b) all five get the wrong hat?

(c) more than one man gets the right hat?

Comment: Welcome to Maths.StackExchange.  What have you tried?

Comment: That's 3 questions and you are expected to try something. This is not a homework answer site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:**

**Exactly** four right is obviously impossible. If four get the right hat, the fifth must also. The probability is $0$.

All wrong is a famous problem, the problem of counting [**Derangements**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

The Wikipedia article is quite helpful. Note that there are $5!$ equally likely ways that the hats can be distributed among the $5$ people.  From the formula in the article, you will find there are $44$ derangements of $5$ objects, so the required probability is $\dfrac{44}{5!}$.

For the probability that more than one gets the right hat, it is easier to find the probability that one or fewer gets the right hat. The probability of none is the answer to (b). For the probability of one, the lucky person can be chosen in $5$ ways. Multiply this by the probability none of the remaining $4$ get the right hat. This again is a derangements problem.  For $4$, you can easily list and count the derangements. There are $9$. So the probability exactly one person gets the right hat is $\dfrac{45}{5!}$.

Thus the probability of (c) is $1-\dfrac{44}{5!}-\dfrac{45}{5!}$.

Comment: Are there any easier method to solve this problem other then Derangement? i have no idea how to use it

Comment: Well, it is is a derangements problem. You can do your own counting. A gets the hat of B. C, D, or E. We count the derangements in which A gets B's hat, and multiply by $4$. Either $B$ get A's hat, and then you can count those cases, or B gets someone else's hat, C's, D's, or E's. You can do a hand count of B gets C's, and multiply by $3$. Total will be $(4)(11)$.

Comment: i still dont understand how to get 44 at (b), after i find 5! (120)what to i do next?

Comment: For (b), the answer is $\frac{44}{120}$. As to the details of getting $44$, I urge you to look at the Wikipedia article. It is now very late here. If tomorrow you still have trouble, I will write out an ugly way to get $44$. (The nice way is covered by the article, and also several MSE answers.)

Comment: i have figured out question(b) but i still do not understand how to get 45/5!

Comment: We are calculating the probability exactly one has his own hat. So we count the number of ways this can happen. The person who gets his own hat can be chosen in $5$ ways. For each of these ways, we count the number of ways the other $4$ get the wrong hat. For example, suppose A gets right hat, how many ways can B, C, D, E get wrong hat? Count them. There are $9$. Multiply by $5$ since there are $5$ ways to choose who gets his own hat. Divide by $120$ to get the probability.  To count the $9$, B can get the hat of C, D, or E.

Comment: We count the ways B can get C's hat, and multiply by $3$. You will find easily that there are $3$ ways for B to get C's hat with neither D nor E getting his own.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is quite trivial. for each man, the probability to get his own hat is 1 to 5, so in total the prob. that exactly 4 men get their own hat should be the prob. that 4 men will succeed with the prob that exactly one man with fail, which is $(\frac{1}{5})^4*(\frac{4}{5})$

NOTE: I'm not certain about the first one.

As for the second, in a simillar way, the prob. that one man goes wrong is 4 to 5, so the prob. that all will be wrong is $(\frac{4}{5})^5$

SECOND ONE IS SURELY CORRECT

Comment: could you please explain what does the power of 5 mean in this solution?

Comment: The power of five signifies the number of successes that is requested. The second answer is with power of 5 because you wanted all the five people to be wrong. About the first one I was wrong because I thought all men should succeed. editing now...

Comment: i think for the first one it would be (1/5)^4.
since it only require 4 people to get the right hats

Comment: but it requires EXACTLY 4 people, which means that the fifth man must fail! see my edited answer

Comment: Oh yea, so for exactly 4 man will succeed it would be (1/5)^4 * (4/5) isn't it?

Comment: @james no, i was wrong. the prob. for exactly four men to succeed is 0, because once 4 men get their own hats, the fifth won't fail!

Answer (score 0):

The question did not ask for the solution of the general derangements problem, just the case of $5$ men and $5$ hats. For this small case it's just as easy to do a direct count. Let the random variable $X$ be the number of men who get their own hats back.

$X=0$: The number of permutations conjugate to (i.e., having the same cycle structure as) $(1\ 2)(3\ 4\ 5)$ or $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$ is $20+24=44$, so $P(X=0)=44/120$.

$X=1$: The number of permutations conjugate to $(1)(2\ 3)(4\ 5)$ or $(1)(2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$ is $15+30=45$, so $P(X=1)=45/120$.

$X=2$: The number of permutations conjugate to $(1)(2)(3\ 4\ 5)$ is $20$, so $P(X=2)=20/120$.

$X=3$: The number of permutations conjugate to $(1)(2)(3)(4\ 5)$ is $10$, so $P(X=3)=10/120$.

$X=4$: impossible, so $P(X=4)=0$.

$X=5$: Just $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$, so $P(X=5)=1/120$.

The answer to (a) is $0$; the answer to (b) is $P(X=0)=44/120=11/30$, and the answer to (c) is $P(X\gt1)=\dfrac{20+10+0+1}{120}=\dfrac{31}{120}$.